# Union table of raster tiles in PostGIS

Tags: postgis, raster, tiles

I have a table of tiled rasters. They often overlap with each other. For instance:

[image]

I would like to eliminate the overlaps. Where a raster overlaps with another raster, it should take the larger value of the two.

I could do this, but it creates one giant raster, and is not tiled. Doing so on some of my datasets crashes PostGIS, so it is not an option.

```
SELECT  st_union(rast, 'max')
FROM    foreign_data.temp_geounits_raster
```

I want to maintain the tiled approach.

Can I use st_intersects to do this?